# DHCP in packet-tracer is not assigning IP correctly, what am I missing?

Tags: subnet

I have the network `172.28.226.128/24`

Whereas first Host should be "`172.28.226.129`" and last Host "`172.28.227.127`"

now, when I try to use dhcp in packet tracer, it assigns the ip "`172.28.226.1`" to the first PC, what am I missing?

```
in packet tracer:
ip dhcp pool xyz
network 172.28.226.128 255.255.255.0
```

Comment: "_I have the network 172.28.226.128/24 Whereas first Host should be "172.28.226.129" and last Host "172.28.227.127"_" No, that is really messed up. If you understand how IPv4 addressing actually works, you can see how that is wrong. I suggest reading [this answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499) for how to calculate such things.

Comment: As others have said, 172.28.226.128/24 is not a valid network. A valid network would be 172.28.226.0/24 or 172.28.226.128/25.

Answer (score 2):

That is correct. The subnet id is 172.28.226.0 with a range of 172.28.226.1 - .254. If you use a /25 mask your subnet ID would be 172.28.226.128 with a useable address range of .129 - .254

Answer (score 0):

In the prefix specification `172.28.226.128/24` the `/24` means the network prefix is 24 bits long, which happens to match exactly the first three octets of the address.

So the network part of the address would be `172.28.226` and the host part would be `128`. The range of address in the prefix thus is `172.28.226.0` to `172.28.226.255` of which `.0` and `.255` are reserved.

Every prefix can be translated to a range of addresses. But not every range of addresses can be described by a single prefix. The range `172.28.226.129` to `172.28.227.127` cannot be described by a single prefix. It takes 8 prefixes to cover that range:

- `172.28.226.129/32` meaning just `172.28.226.129`
- `172.28.226.130/31` meaning `172.28.226.130` - `172.28.226.131`
- `172.28.226.132/30` meaning `172.28.226.132` - `172.28.226.135`
- `172.28.226.136/29` meaning `172.28.226.136` - `172.28.226.143`
- `172.28.226.144/28` meaning `172.28.226.144` - `172.28.226.159`
- `172.28.226.160/27` meaning `172.28.226.160` - `172.28.226.191`
- `172.28.226.192/26` meaning `172.28.226.192` - `172.28.226.255`
- `172.28.227.0/25` meaning `172.28.227.0` - `172.28.227.127`

If you were to add `172.28.226.128` to the range it goes down to just two prefixes needed to cover the range:

- `172.28.226.128/25` meaning `172.28.226.128` - `172.28.226.255`
- `172.28.227.0/25` meaning `172.28.227.0` - `172.28.227.127`

The range of addresses assigned by DHCP will always be a subset of the addresses in the network segment as it will have to exclude the reserved addresses as well as the gateway address. You may want to exclude more addresses as well to allow for some static addresses an possibly another DHCP server with another range in the same network prefix.

The range of assigned addresses does not have to match a prefix, so you absolutely can have a DHCP server hand out addresses from the range `172.28.226.129` to `172.28.227.127`, but in order to do so you need to use a shorter network prefix covering a lot more addresses. Your network prefix would need to cover at least 512 addresses.

You can use the network prefix `172.28.226.0/23` which is the range `172.28.226.0` to `172.28.227.255` for a total of 512 addresses and you would be using only 255 of those for DHCP assignments.